# Create different dataframes from list in python

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have a data

```
#create some data with Names column
data = pd.DataFrame({'Names': ['Joe', 'John', 'Jasper', 'Jez'] *4, 'Add': ['Lo', 'Po', 'Fa',     
'It']*4,'Ob1' : np.random.rand(16), 'Ob2' : np.random.rand(16)})
```

[image]

I want to create sub data for a few of the Names & Add for example for Name= "Joe" & Add = "Lo" another one for John & Po which should look like this:

```
df1:
```

[image]

df2 :

[image]

I used the following codes to do so :

```
#Mapping file
data2 = pd.DataFrame({
"Names": ["Joe", "John"],
"Add": ["Lo", "Po"]})

 tuples = [tuple(x) for x in data2.values]
 my_dfs = [data[(data['Names'] == mytuple[0]) & (data['Add'] == mytuple[1])] for mytuple in    
 tuples]
 for my_df in my_dfs:
     print(my_df)
```

This creates a list with all the dataframes. How can I create separate dataframes from this list ?

Comment: `"This creates a list with all the dataframes. How can I create separate dataframes from this list ?"` This question is not clear. You already have separated dataframes, in a list. You even print these separated dataframes. What else do you want to do with these dataframes?

Comment: I want to extract them from list & make individual data frames so that I can implement different functions on each of them. Basically unpack the list to create different dataframes

Comment: You can store each dataframe in a separate variable like `df1 = my_df[0] df2 = my_df[1] etc` but this brings no actual value over just having them in the list

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use groupby:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Names': ['Joe', 'John', 'Jasper', 'Jez'] *4, 
                     'Add': ['Lo', 'Po', 'Fa', 'It']*4,
                     'Ob1' : np.random.rand(16), 
                     'Ob2' : np.random.rand(16)})

c = [gr[1] for gr in data.groupby(['Names', 'Add'])]
print(c[3])

Names Add Ob1 Ob2
1 John Po 0.930007 0.994919
5 John Po 0.803813 0.946720
9 John Po 0.561481 0.620958
13 John Po 0.238159 0.863743
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's help. Another way to solve this problem :

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Names': ['Joe', 'John', 'Jasper', 'Jez'] *4, 'Add':        
['Lo', 'Po', 'Fa',    
'It']*4,'Ob1' : np.random.rand(16), 'Ob2' : np.random.rand(16)})

 # create a dataframe of all combinations
 combinations=data[['Names','Add']].drop_duplicates()
 comboList=list(zip(combinations['Names'],combinations['Add']))



 for i,combo in enumerate(comboList):

     subset=data[(data['Names']==combo[0]) & (data['Add']==combo[1])]

     # run multiple functions on subset here
     print(subset.head())
```